# Base64 encoded image is different from what was saved

Tags: java

I use `ImageIO` to save `Base64` image string to a file:

```
public static String decodeBase64AndSaveImage(String data) throws IOException, BadRequestException {
    try {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String base64Image = data.split(",")[1];
        byte[] imageBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
        String imageId = generateRandomKey(15);
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", getImageFile(imageId));
        return imageId;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Bad image data");
    }
}
```

I pass the following string to this method:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAADklEQVQIW2NgQAXGZHAAGioAza6+Hk0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

In the following test I check that the if the saved content to the file is the same as what was passed to the method:

```
        byte[] base64ImageData = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(imageFile));
        Assert.assertEquals("wrong image data stored", DUMMY_IMAGE
                .split(",")[1], new String(base64ImageData,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

But it returns a different string:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAADklEQVR42mNgQAXGZHAAGioAzTktUZoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

Why does this happen ?

**Note 1**

It doesn't compare `data:image/png;base64,` so it's not the reason that it fails.

Comment: What happens if you use a command-line base64 encode/decode program to dump the contents of the file?  Is the problem introduced in the read or the write? Is there really a problem here? Does the second base64 string produce a different image? Did you step through the program in the debugger and compare the binary data to what is expected?  There's a lot of troubleshooting you can do here, and you're in a much better position to do it than us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are base64 decoding the string, using ImageIO to create a BufferedImage, converting it back to a PNG, and re-base64 encoding this result.

```
byte[] imageBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new 
   ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
String imageId = generateRandomKey(15);

// re-encode
ImageIO.write(img, "png", getImageFile(imageId));
```

This all works fine. But the image encoder is encoding the image in a slightly different way to the original. They are both though valid PNG files and both valid base64 strings.

I decoded both strings and found they produced valid PNG files which look identical, but were encoded in different ways.

Comment: Exactly. Is there a way to encode image in exactly the same way ? Or it doesn't make sense to have such test ?

Comment: I assume it wasn't encoded with ImageIO in the first place? No, it doesn't seem to make sense to expect it to be output 100% identical binary. You could compare the buffered images for the same bitmap, but you have to ask yourself the point of the test and the how likely it is to fail and if you are in the end just testing code libraries, rather than paths of your own code. I would test the encoding and decoding of "some binary" binary to base64 and back. Ignore that it's PNG data for this test. Then perhaps other tests that you are encoding / decoding a PNG correctly.